# How to select multiple values in flatlist based on there key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm using react native's powerful flatlist this is my array which is like this:

```
data =   [
      {Color:[{'label':'BLUE','value':'10'}, {'label':'RED','value':'11'}]},
      {Size:[{'label':'SMALL','value':'13'},{'label':'BIG','value':'12'}]}
      ]
```

and here it Is my flatlist

```
<FlatList data={data}
              numColumns={1}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
              extraData={this.state}
              ItemSeparatorComponent={FlatListItemSeparator}
              renderItem={({item, index}) => {
                return(
                <View >
                <Text >{Object.keys(item)}</Text>
                <FlatList data={item[Object.keys(item)]}
                numColumns={5}
                keyExtractor={(index) => "D"+index.toString()}
                extraData={this.state}
                renderItem={({item, index}) => {
                  return(
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._handleclick(index, item)} style={[
                            styles.Buttoncolor, this.state.selected == index+item.label
                              ? styles.onfocusbutton
                              : null
                          ]}>
                          <Text style={[styles.textcolor,this.state.selected == index+item.label?styles.white:null]}>{item.label}</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        )
                }
                }/>
              </View>)}}/>
```

this is the function where im matching the index of item..

```
  _handleclick = (index, item) => {
        this.setState({selected: index+item.label, selectedColor: item.value})
      }
```

here it is what I tried :->

I call hand click function match its value with index+label name and it get change itself but
when I click on BLUE it change its color but when I click on SMALL
it can change itself but blue gets its previous condition

now here's main what I want to do :->

I want to select only one item based on there array which is 'Color'
I want that when I click on BLUE it can be change it color .
and if I click also on SMALL it can also change color itself that two value need to be stored.

I hope you could easily understand.
thanks in advance

UPDATE 1

STATUS :**SOLVED**

**Changes**

```
_handleclick = (index, item,objectname) => {
         const {selected,result} = this.state
         let selectedIndex = this.state.selected.indexOf(item.value);
            if(selectedIndex == -1){
           let my =   this.state.result.filter((e)=>{return e[objectname]})
             selected.forEach((items) => {
                    let arrayofattribute =   result.filter((e)=>{return e[objectname]})
                    arrayofattribute.forEach((value,index)=>{
                    newval =  value[objectname].map((val,i)=>{
                        if(items == val.label)
                        {
                          selected.splice(selected.indexOf(val.label),1)
                        }
                      })
                    })
             })
            this.setState({selected:[item.label,...this.state.selected]})
          }
      }
```

in Flatlist render

```
<TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => this._handleCategoryColor(index, item,objectname)}

                        style={[
                          styles.Buttoncolor,

                          this.state.selected.indexOf(item.label) != -1
                            ? styles.onfocusbutton
                            : null,
                        ]}>
                        <Text
                          style={[
                            styles.textcolor,
                            this.state.selected.indexOf(item.label) != -1
                              ? styles.white
                              : null,
                          ]}>
                          {item.label}

                        </Text>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try array instead of storing single selected item,

make selected state as empty array when you are declaring.

```
...
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._handleclick(index, item)} style={[
                            styles.Buttoncolor, this.state.selected.indexOf(index+item.label) != -1
                              ? styles.onfocusbutton
                              : null
]}>
    <Text style={[styles.textcolor, this.state.selected.indexOf(index+item.label) != -1?styles.white:null]}>{item.label}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

here is you handle method, push new selected item to selected array

```
_handleclick = (index, item) => {
        let selectedIndex = this.state.selected.indexOf(index+item.label);
        if(selectedIndex== -1){
          this.setState({selected: [...this.state.selected,index+item.label], selectedColor: item.value})
        }

      }
```

Comment: its selecting all the value in array and can't even get in previous condition.and I want to select only one in Color and one in size how can I do it

Comment: then you need to separate selected for both, like selectedColor and selectedSize. remove array thing also.

Comment: I can't do it like this your approach is right to take selected values in array which is I want but only one value from per array

Comment: thanks man I've done my work using your solution you can check my post what changes I made to work...

Answer (score 1):

Probably the issue is with the function arguments assignments. If you see both `renderItem` methods in `Flatlist` uses `renderItem={({item, index})` so the last `renderItem` can access the above `item, index`. There's an confusion when `onPress` called, which item or index to put in the callback.
Please try to add the arg different names. Like

```
<FlatList data={data}
   numColumns={1}
   keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
   extraData={this.state}
   ItemSeparatorComponent={FlatListItemSeparator}
   renderItem={({item, index}) => {
   return(
     <View >
     <Text >{Object.keys(item)}</Text>
     <FlatList data={item[Object.keys(item)]}
                numColumns={5}
                keyExtractor={(index) => "D"+index.toString()}
                extraData={this.state}
                renderItem={({set, key}) => {
                  return(
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._handleclick(key, set)} style={[
                            styles.Buttoncolor, this.state.selected == index+item.label
                              ? styles.onfocusbutton
                              : null
                          ]}>
                          <Text style={[styles.textcolor,this.state.selected == index+item.label?styles.white:null]}>{item.label}</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        )
                }
                }/>
              </View>)}}/>
```

Let me know if this fixes your issue.
Happy coding. :)

Comment: no it's not... it gives error that set.label is not a function and read the question first what I want to do thanks..

Comment: @Tanveerbyn chill bro, with that attitude you won't be helped much.

Comment: It's okay, but be always polite, especially if someone is taking their own time to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If I correcty understood you need to select just one option for each property (colors and sizes). So you need to have a field in your state for each element you want to be saved.

Your `_handleClick` function could be something like this:

```
_handleclick = (index, item) => {
  const { Color } = this.state.data[0];
  const { Size } = this.state.data[1];
  this.setState(state => ({
    selectedColor: Color.find(color => color.label === item.label)
      ? index + item.label
      : state.selectedColor,
    selectedSize: Size.find(size => size.label === item.label)
      ? index + item.label
      : state.selectedSize,
  }));
};
```

Every time you click on an element you need to know if it's a color or a size and then correctly update the right field. Maybe this is not the most performant way, but it works.

Then, in your render method, in order to assign style you could check both conditions:

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => this._handleclick(index, item)}
  style={[
    styles.Buttoncolor,
    this.state.selectedSize == index + item.label ||
    this.state.selectedColor == index + item.label
      ? styles.onfocusbutton
      : null,
  ]}>
  <Text
    style={[
      styles.textcolor,
      this.state.selectedSize == index + item.label ||
      this.state.selectedColor == index + item.label
        ? styles.white
        : null,
    ]}>
    {item.label}
  </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

I tried to reproduce your question in [this snack](https://snack.expo.io/@milore/carefree-peach), you can take a look.

Comment: sry but I need to do this in dynamic way 'Color' this is fixed approach which I've done previous I need to do it on dynamic content this why.. and I want all selected value in an array btw than for your response..